# Line from one widget to another and compare their contents

Tags: flutter

I need to draw a line from one widget to another and compare their contents. For example, it may be necessary to match words in some test.
Do you have any ideas how this can be done?
I know how to draw a line by coordinates or by clicking on the screen, but then how can I understand from which widget and to which widget the line is drawn? And how do I access the contents of these widgets?[image]

Comment: can you please share the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Widget Inspector on Dart Dev Tools.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I briefly read about the Widget Inspector and didn't quite understand how it could help me. Perhaps the question was composed incorrectly, changed it and added the desired result. If you think this is still what I need, confirm it and I'll go figure it out